# Explanation of Spark ML CountVectorizer output

Tags: apache-spark-mllib

Please help understand the output of the Spark ML [CountVectorizer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer) and suggest which  documentation explains it.

```
val cv = new CountVectorizer()
  .setInputCol("Tokens")
  .setOutputCol("Frequencies")
  .setVocabSize(5000)
  .setMinTF(1)
  .setMinDF(2)
val fittedCV = cv.fit(tokenDF.select("Tokens"))
fittedCV.transform(tokenDF.select("Tokens")).show(false)
```

2374 should be the number of terms (words) in the dictionary. 
What is the "[2,6,328,548,1234]"?

Are they indices of the words "[airline, bag, vintage, world, champion]" in the dictionary? If so, why the same word "airline" has a different index "0" in the second line?

```
+------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|Tokens                                    |Frequencies                                                     |
+------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
...
|[airline, bag, vintage, world, champion]  |(2374,[2,6,328,548,1234],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])                 |
|[airline, bag, vintage, jet, set, brown]  |(2374,[0,2,6,328,405,620],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])            |
+------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+


  [1]: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#countvectorizer) explaining the basics. However this is pretty bare.

Yes. The numbers represent the words in a vocabulary index. However the order in the frequencies vector does not correspond to the order in tokens vector. 
`airline, bag, vintage` are in both rows, hence they correspond to indices [2,6,328]. But you can't rely on the same order.

The row data type is a [SparseVector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector). The first array, shows the indices and the second the values.

e.g

```
vector[328] 
   => 1.0
```

a mapping could be as follows:

```
vocabulary
airline 328
bag 6
vintage 2

Frequencies
2734, [2, 6 ,328], [99, 5, 7]

# counts
vintage x 99
bag x 5
airline 7
```

In order to get the words back , you can do a lookup in the vocabulary. This needs to be broadcasted to different workers. You also most probably want to explode the counts per doc into separate rows.

Here is some `python` code snippet to extract top 25 frequent words per doc with a udf into separate rows and compute the mean for each word

```
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Row

vocabulary = sc.broadcast(fittedCV.vocabulary)

def _top_scores(v):
    # create count tuples for each index(i) in a vector(v)
    # `.item()` is used, because in python the count value is a numpy datatype, in `scala` it will be just double 

    counts = [Row(i=i.item(),count=v[i.item()].item()) for i in v.indices]
    # => [Row(i=2, count=30, Row(i=362, count=40)]

    # return 25 top count rows
    counts = sorted(counts, reverse=True, key=lambda x: x.count)
    return counts[:25]

top_scores = F.udf(_top_scores, T.ArrayType(T.StructType().add('i', T.IntegerType()).add('count', T.DoubleType())))                  
vec_to_word = F.udf(_vecToWord, T.StringType())


def _vecToWord(i):
    return vocabulary.value[i]



res = df.withColumn('word_count', explode(top_scores('Frequencies')))
=>
+-----+-----+----------+ 
doc_id, ..., word_count
             (i,  count)
+-----+-----+----------+
4711, ...,   (2, 30.0)
4711, ...,   (362, 40.0)
+-----+-----+----------+

res = res \
    .groupBy('word_count.i').agg( \
        avg('word_count.count').alias('mean')
    .orderBy('mean', ascending=False)

res = res.withColumn('token', vec_to_word('i')) 


=>
+---+---------+----------+ 
 i,   token,    mean
+---+---------+----------+ 
 2,   vintage,  15
 328, airline,  30  

+--+----------+----------+
```