# PySpark array column to numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, pyspark

I have an array column in pyspark df as follows:

```
[1,2,3]
[0,2]
[1]
```

I'd like to generate a numpy array from it as:

```
[[0,1,1,1]
[1,0,1,0]
[0,1,0,0]]
```

I've tried solutions using CountVectorizer but it has issue as in [Explanation of Spark ML CountVectorizer output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59355956/explanation-of-spark-ml-countvectorizer-output). My dataset is also very large which `np.array(df.select('col').collect())` does not work.

Any possible solutions?

Comment: Shouldn't the 1th item row the 2nd row be `1`, not `0`?

Comment: oh yes typo. will modify. thx

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.get_dummies.html

Comment: I'm using spark3.1 so can't test this quickly.. I think this won't work for my case